# How to make a column aligned to bottom inside a stack scroll when there is not enough space?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Overflow error]

I am trying to create a modal form. The modal content should stay at the bottom, and can reach max height of `windowHeight - top safe area - 56px` depending on available space. If there is no more space, it should scroll the body area, that is the form fields and submit button.

Corresponding code:

```dart
Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => navigator.pop()
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(...radius, background...),
                  child: SafeArea(
                    top: false,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            // Title & close button
                          ],
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(...),
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  CoreTextField(...),
                                  CoreTextField(...),
                                  CoreTextField(...),
                                  CoreTextField(...),
                                  CoreTextField(...),
                                  CoreTextField(...),
                                  CoreButton(...)
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the Container in a SingleChildScrollView?

Comment: Swapping with parent container of `SingleChildScrollView`? Tried it, and the result is same.

Comment: It's the stack inside a bottom sheet?

Comment: No, it's set to Scaffold body.

Comment: Try `Positioned.fill(top: 56, child: ...)` instead of `Align`.

Comment: `Positioned.fill` will make the card taller than necessary. `windowHeight - top safe area - 56px` is the **max height** I want to achieve, it's not the fixed height.

Answer (score 1):

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    InkWell(
      onTap: () => navigator.pop()
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 56.0
          ), //maxHeight of the window - 56.0
          decoration: BoxDecoration(...radius, background...),
          child: SafeArea(
            top: false,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    // Title & close button
                  ],
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                ),
                Expanded( //Use Expanded instead of Container
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(...),
                    child: Center(
                     child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CoreTextField(...),
                        CoreTextField(...),
                        CoreTextField(...),
                        CoreTextField(...),
                        CoreTextField(...),
                        CoreTextField(...),
                        CoreButton(...)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Use Expanded instead of `Container`, the `Expanded` will try to use all the available space and then the `SingleChildScrollView` will scroll in that space if the column didn't fit

**UPDATE**

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double statusBar = MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top;
    double maxSize = (height -56.0 - statusBar)/height;
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.loose,
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          onTap: () => null, //navigator.pop()
        ),
        DraggableScrollableSheet(
          maxChildSize: maxSize, 
          minChildSize: 0.3,// whatever value you want for the minimum, less than max
          initialChildSize: maxSize, 
          //or if you don't want it fully expanded just give it a fraction of maxSize
          //it has to be between maxChildSize and minChildSize
          builder: (context, scrollController){
             return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(...radius, background...),
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        // Title & close button
                      ],
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          controller: scrollController,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(...),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            CoreTextField(...),
                            CoreTextField(...),
                            CoreTextField(...),
                            CoreTextField(...),
                            CoreTextField(...),
                            CoreTextField(...),
                            CoreButton(...)
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It makes the card full screen.

Comment: in that case what about using a BoxConstraint with maxHeight of windowHeight - top safe area - 56px in the Container below IntrinsicHeight

Comment: It then always stays at that maxHeight.

Comment: you want to move it up and down?

Comment: It should adjust based on available space, and stick to bottom on taller devices. Figured it out withe the help of a coworker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListView or SingleChildScrolView

Comment: As you can see in the question details, I am already using SingleChildScrollView. Tried ListView too.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had to use `Column` and put `Align` inside `Expanded`.

```dart
Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
     InkWell(
        onTap: navigator.pop,
     ),
     Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Column( // This is an additional wrapper to hold the minimum top spacing and the modal content
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox( // Provides minimum spacing at the top on smaller viewports
                height: 56 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
            ),
            Expanded( // Occupies rest of the screen and provides constraints
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, // Now that we have constraints, we can push the children down using align
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(... color & radius ...),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // Required. Shrinks the contents to minimum possible height.
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(... title & close button ...),
                      Flexible( // Not expanded, but flexible. Unlike Expanded, it doesn't force child to take up entire space. This is needed for SingleChildScrollView to work
                        child: SingleChildScrollView( // Makes the form fields scrollable
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(SPACING_UNIT * 5, 0, SPACING_UNIT * 5, SPACING_UNIT * 5),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                CoreTextField(),
                                CoreTextField(),
                                CoreTextField(),
                                CoreTextField(),
                                CoreTextField(),
                                CoreTextField(),
                                SafeArea(
                                  top: false,
                                  child: CoreButton(),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
    )
)
```